# PHP countdown outputs negative value

Tags: php, server-side, countdown

I am using PHP as server side language to display a countdown. It does work well (keeping in ming the limitation of server side countdowns) but it goes to a negative countdown once the date has expired.

For example:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$date = strtotime("November 22, 2017 12:01 AM");
$remaining = $date - time();
$days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
$hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600);
$minutes_remaining = floor(($remaining % 3600) / 60);
?>
```

Once the November 22 is finished the countdown will output negative values. Can you please help me with how to hide the countdown once the `$date` has expired?

I am outputting the result using the below code:

```
<?php echo $days_remaining?> : <?php echo $hours_remaining?> : <?php echo $minutes_remaining?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a simple check for positivity of the `$remaining`value using [if statement](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$date = strtotime("November 22, 2017 12:01 AM");
$remaining = $date - time();

if ($remaining > 0) {
    $days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
    $hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600);
    $minutes_remaining = floor(($remaining % 3600) / 60);
}
```

In output file:

```
<? if ($remaining > 0) { ?>
    <?= $days_remaining ?> : <?= $hours_remaining ?> : <?= $minutes_remaining ?>
<? } ?>
```

It's more readable to use the syntax `<?= $var ?>` to output something in PHP (option [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) must have `On` value in `php.ini`).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$date = strtotime("November 21, 2017 12:01 AM");
$remaining = $date - time();

if( $remaining >= 0 )
{
    $days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
    $hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600);
    $minutes_remaining = floor(($remaining % 3600) / 60);
    echo $days_remaining, ":", $hours_remaining, ":", $minutes_remaining;
}
else
    echo "Done";
```